# Drupal cck address field

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

We have created a registration form in drupal 6 and used cck address field for location information on the given site.

https://stagingconference.calea.org/user/register

We have a section for register. Moreover, the action we need is if I fill the information in register more the new user will be created with the location information that is in the register more block. but its not inserting the location details into database.

It accepts the location details for the main user that is outside the register more but not inserting the location details that is in the register more.

is there any idea about the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of cck fields in registration.You can enable profile module and add the custom profile field whatever you want.Also this module will update the user object (global $user).

For the more info about the profile module follow [Community Documentation for profile module](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--profile--profile.module/6)

Comment: thank you for your answer but i figure out this by modification in ubercart checkout module.